# Why does my object not have a material?

Tags: materials, shaders, edges

I can't assign smooth shading to my object (clicking smooth in the shading tab on the left side yields not result). When trying to find out why I noticed that it doesn't have a material in the material panel (bottom right). Why?

This is a custom shaped object I made from a cylinder mesh.

[image]

Comment: Looking at your screen short, I suspect that the object does have a material. The material context button is set for materials, but the slider in the properties pane is not at the top of its range, and is far enough down, that the top panes are not visible.If you move the slider up, you will at least find the dialog box for adding materials.

Comment: You need to be in "Object" Mode to set the shading to smooth.

Answer (score 2):

On the bottom right, scroll up and you will see the panel to add materials.
Even if you don't assign a material to your mesh the smooth shading option should still work.
From what I can see, your mesh just has inverted normals. 
Go to the panel on the left and click "Recalculate"
if that doesnt work, then click "Flip Direction".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I needed to scroll up and that my normals were inverted, but I still can't get smooth shading. I click smooth on any of those options on the top left and they do nothing.

Comment: can you post some pictures? Or a blend file? Perhaps smooth shading works but not like you were expecting it to?